# Elastic IP on Amazon EC2 - How does this effect rate limiting?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, debian

I had a quick question. I have been reading about elastic IP's with Amazon EC2 instances. I was wondering, a lot of the stuff I do with my server is based on IP limits, like for example google map geocoding which is limited to 2,500 per IP (I beleive it is limited on IP not server).

Firstly, if I have 3 elastic IP's connected to my Amazon EC2 instance, does that mean that effectively my server can appear to be located on three different IP's, so I can effectively triple the amount of google map geocodes I can make?

Secondly, is there a way to determine which IP my server uses, and can this be changed whilst the server is running?

I'm not trying to do anything illegal, I have emailed google about this as well, but it is just to further my knowledge and see if this is possible / legal. Any information would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Elastic IP can only be bound to one running instance. Remapping IPs (for example changing to another IP, or giving the currently used IP to another instance) is possible during runtime.

See the [Amazon Feature guide and their FAQs at the bottom.](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346)

As a sidenote, I think a lot of Google Maps API request are now on a user-basis (e.g. you have to send a token specific to your account) and not on a per-IP-basis.